# Random Duplicate Transactions in Authorize.Net

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net

Having an emergency situation. Currently on my site I have some customers that are being charged multiple times for the same order. The payment gateway is Authorize.Net and the store front platform is Magento Enterprise. What could be causing this? Bad code, server error, etc? This has never happened before and totally random. If this isn’t enough info to help please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a coding issue but trying to spot the code will be difficult in a site like this. A developer will need to go through and review the entire checkout code to look for potential errors.

The best course of action is to look to see how far apart the transactions are. If they are very close together (i.e. a few  minutes or less) you can try to fix this by setting the duplicate transaction window to a value large enough to block the duplicates from happening. In other words, if the duplicate transactions are happening within 60 seconds of each other,  update the Authorize.Net code to set `x_duplicate_window` to a value of 180 (this value is seconds). That *should* prevent the duplicate orders from happening.